# react-native-map marker flickering/shivering on location changing

Tags: react-native-maps

```
interface Props {
  carLocation: UserLocation;
}

export const CarMarker: FC<Props> = memo(({carLocation}) => {
  const currentLocationMarketRef = useRef<MapMarker>(null);
  const currentUserLocationRef = useRef(
    new AnimatedRegion({
      latitude: carLocation?.latitude,
      longitude: carLocation?.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.012,
      longitudeDelta: 0.012,
    }),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const newMarkerLocation = {
      latitude: carLocation?.latitude,
      longitude: carLocation?.longitude,
      useNativeDriver: false,
      duration: 5000,
    };

    if (isAndroid) {
      currentLocationMarketRef.current?.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
        newMarkerLocation,
        5000,
      );
    } else {
      currentUserLocationRef.current.timing(newMarkerLocation as any).start();
    }
  }, [carLocation]);

  return (
    <Marker.Animated
      ref={currentLocationMarketRef}
      coordinate={currentUserLocationRef.current as any}
      anchor={{x: 0.5, y: 0.5}}
      rotation={carLocation.heading || 0}
      tracksViewChanges={false}
      flat
      icon={require('assets/Map/CarOnMap.png')}
    />
  );
});
```

[Gif with proplem showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4ac.gif)

I need to make a smooth marker animation that represents the user's location. But when it got new coordinates - the marker does some flickering/shivering.
How to solve this issue?